# htaccess redirect only subdirectory requests (not requests for TLD)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, indexing, subdirectory, permanent

I moved my blog from example.com to example.com/blog. I now have a splash page at example.com. I would like old blog post requests like example.com/2011/example-post to redirect to example.com/blog/2011/example-post; but requests to example.com to be allowed with no redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/.+)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

this will redirect all that have digits 4 digits (year) and something after slash so everything you have in example.com will work like regular page `example.com/about.html`